# How to get jsonencode data in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel

controller

```
public function rooms_detail(Request $request)
{   
    $data['room_id']          = $request->id;
    $data['result']           = Rooms::find($request->id);

    echo $data['result'];

    return view('rooms.rooms_detail', $data);
}
```

view:rooms/rooms_detail

```
@foreach($result as $row)
    <div class="hero-text">{{ $row->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

In this code I have a controller function where I am run a query inside the Rooms Model which works fine and my data look like `{"id":16,"user_id":10088,"name":"5 \u2b50 RESORT RETREAT W\/HEATED POOL SPRAWLING GROUNDS"}`. but I am unable to fetch this data in my view file. So, How can I ndo this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I don't see a problem with your current code. What is your issue or error?

Comment: What does {{ $row->name }} show in your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to loop it. since you are using `find` function. Just call it directly on your view

```
<div class="hero-text">{{ $result->name }}</div>
```

`find` function will give you the Model if it find something or it will return null

or if you want change you eloquent query.

```
$data['result'] = Rooms::where('id', $request->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Docs of Laravel, you may also retrieve single records using find or first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

So

```
$data['result']           = Rooms::find($request->id);
```

return a single model not collection of models.
You should change your code in view:rooms/rooms_detail

```
//@foreach($result as $row) => remove foreach
     <div class="hero-text">{{ $result->name }}</div>
//@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I would return the data like this in your controller:

```
return response()->view('rooms.rooms_detail', [
   $result => $data['result'],
   $roomID => $data['room_id']
]);
```

It's the recommended correct way to return responses https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses

And then in your blade:

```
<div class="hero-text">{{ $result->name }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert collection to array since you are using `eloquents find` method which will return a `collection` not an `array`

You can simply use the below code

```
public function rooms_detail(Request $request)
{   
     $room_id         = $request->id;
     $data           = Rooms::find($request->id);

    echo $data['result'];

    return view('rooms.rooms_detail', $data);
}
```

and then in your view

```
<div class="hero-text">{{ $data->name }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function rooms_detail(Request $request)
{   
    $room           = Rooms::find($request->id);
    return view('rooms.rooms_detail')->with('room',$room);
}
```

**At View data page**

```html
 
    <div class="hero-text">{{ $room->name }}</div>
```

you are fetching only one data so do not need to loop